# Recognize HTTP 304 in service worker / fetch()

Tags: http, caching, http-caching, service-worker, http-status-code-304

I build a service worker which always responds with data from the cache and then, in the background, sends a request to the server. If the server responds with `HTTP 304 - not modified` everything is fine, if the server responds with `HTTP 200`, that means the data was changed and the new file is put into the cache, also the user is notified and asked for a page refresh.

I use the `not-modified-since` / `last-modified` headers to make sure the client gets the most up-to-date version. When a request is sent via `fetch()` the request passes the HTTP-cache on it's way to the network - also the response passes the HTTP cache when it arrives on the client. The problem is when the response has the status `304` - not modified the HTTP cache responds to the service worker with the cached version and replaces the status with `200` (as it is described in the [fetch specification - HTTP-network-or-cache-fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch)). In the service worker there is no possibility to find out whether the `200` response was initially sent by the server (the user needs to be updated) or it was sent by the cache and the server originally responded with `304` (most up-to-date version is already loaded).

There is the [cache-mode flag](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/) which can be set to `no-cache`, but this bypasses the HTTP-cache also when the request is sent to the server, which means that the `if-modified-since` header is not set and the server has no chance to find out which version the client has. Also this flag is only supported by firefox nightly right now.

I think the best solution is to set a custom HTTP header like `x-was-modified` when the server responds with `200`. This custom header can be accessed in the service worker and can be used to find out whether a resource was updated or not - even if the HTTP cache replaces the `304` status with `200`.

- Is this a legit solution/workaround? Are there any suggested approaches to solve this problem?
- Should I even rely on HTTP headers which are supposed to handle the HTTP cache when implementing the service worker cache? Or should I rather use custom `x-if-modified-since` / `x-last-modified` headers and use indexedDB to store the information on the client and append it to each request?
- Why does `fetch()` even replace the `304` code with `200` if there is a up-to-date version in the cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t rely on the status code (304 vs. 200) to determine whether something has changed. What if some other part of your code requests the same resource, thus updating the browser’s cache?

Instead, simply compare the response’s `Last-Modified` header to what you sent in `If-Modified-Since`, or whatever you last saw in `Last-Modified`. If the values don’t match, something has changed.

For more precision (if the data can change several times in 1 second), consider using [`ETag`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) instead of `Last-Modified`.

> Why does `fetch()` even replace the `304` code with `200` if there is a up-to-date version in the cache?

Because usually people just want to get fresh content, regardless of where it comes from. A 304 response is only interesting to those who implement their own HTTP caches.

Comment: "_Instead, simply compare the response’s Last-Modified header to what you sent in If-Modified-Since_"  But I cant access `if-modified-since` in the service worker since the request hits the service worker before the http-cache (which adds this header to the request)

Comment: @SvenKeinath “or whatever you last saw in `Last-Modified`”. That is, remember the value of `Last-Modified` right where your service worker’s cache is.

Comment: e.g storing the `Las-Modified` value in indexedDB?

Comment: @SvenKeinath Are you using the [`Cache` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) to store the response after `fetch()`? If so, I think you can simply compare the `Last-Modified` of the response currently in the `Cache`, and that of the newly `fetch`ed response.