# Conditional GET ignored with fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch-api, if-modified-since

I am fetching and parsing an RSS feed (https://www.mangaupdates.com/rss.php) with Discord.js/Node.js. I'm currently trying to add a conditional `If-Modified-Since` header to make a conditional GET request to the RSS feed. Here is my code:

```
fetch(mangaUpdatesRSS, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'If-Modified-Since': new Date().toUTCString()}
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.status);
```

The response status is always `200` even though it should only be making a request if it's been modified since the time of the `fetch` command is called.

Comment: is this working for RSS feeds to only get when there is update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch API replaces `304` with `200` internally even if the requested resource is up to date. There's nothing you can do about it.

Check out [Recognize HTTP 304 in service worker / fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137776/recognize-http-304-in-service-worker-fetch)

Comment: This didn't seem to fix the issue. It is still outputting 200. I also think the fetch API [documentation](https://javascript.info/fetch-api) says that `cache` defaults to `no-store` if `If-Modified-Since` is set as a header